# Button and link styles behaving differently

Tags: css, button, hyperlink, styles, anchor

I have two elements (`<a>` and `<button>`), both of which are sharing the same classes from Tachyons:

```
<a class="f4 br2 fw9 pa3 bg-dark-blue white link db tc lh-solid fixed left-1 bottom-1 right-1 mla mra z-1  " href="/edit-profile/photos"
>Confirm account</a>

<button class="f4 br2 fw9 pa3 bg-dark-blue white link db tc lh-solid fixed left-1 bottom-1 right-1 mla mra z-1  " type="submit">Next</button>
```

The expected behaviour is that they will both be the same width, and yet they're different (despite the same styles).

Any idea what's going on here?

[Here's a Codepen demonstrating the issue.](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/MQMmVo)

Comment: Browsers have different default styles for `<button>` and `<a>`. Give the button `min-width: 100%` and it will expand.

Comment: Hi @sol adding `min-width: 100%` unfortunately does not make them the same width

Comment: Can you change the markup or just styles?

Comment: It does. There is also a border on the `button` by default. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQJWBa (position: fixed removed so you can see them)

Comment: Yup, you're right @sol. Makes them behave the same which is the desired behaviour. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case the button has a border and a different font, which is a default style for your browser. Each browser have it's own defaults for every type of elements, that's why a button and a link would look the way they do without any styling. In a matter of fact it isn't right to say "without any styling", it is rather "without any **additional** styling":

```html
<button>I'm a button</button>
<a href="">I'm a link</a>
```

I didn't go through all the css you have, because you have 17 classes for a single element and I'm too lazy for it, but it actually possible to have different styles for different elements with a common class:

```css
.awesome {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  font-family: Arial, serif;
}
div.awesome {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  border-color: royalblue;
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkslateblue;
}
span.awesome {
  background-color: orangered;
  border-color: firebrick;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="awesome">I'm a div</div>
<span class="awesome">I'm a span</span>
```